# Gen_bunny (Erlang / Elixir) subscribe to queue (Rabbitmq) using bunnyc

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, amqp, elixir

Does anyone know how can I subscribe to Rabbitmq queue using gen_bunny?

I am able to connect and push the message and by using get method I can also receive message. However, I cant find out how to subscribe to a queue and get the message in my gen_server.

Comment: I haven't tried it but they do have an example about using the gen_bunny behavior in the repo: https://github.com/mochi/gen_bunny/blob/master/docs/examples/example_gb.erl

Comment: Thanks Jose, I checked that but it doesnt show example of subscribing of queue. I am able to use get method to receive message but I want to subscribe to queue. I am using https://github.com/mochi/gen_bunny/blob/master/src/bunnyc.erl.

Comment: BTW, in bunnyc.erl they have two functions, register_return_handler and register_flow_handler where we can pass the name and PID. but there is no description for that and it doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: I wrote a demonstration here: https://github.com/wmealing/bunny-cowboy-websocket  A little old now but should give you the gist.